# Does Facade in Laravel implements Facade or Proxy Pattern?

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, facade, proxy-pattern

As I understood, the **Facade Pattern**'s intent is

> to provide a **unified interface** to a **set of interfaces** in a **subsystem**. Facade defines a higher-level interface that makes the **subsystem** easier to use. This can be used to simplify a number of complicated object interactions into a single interface.

[image]

From what i understood is, the pattern's goal is to hide complexity in subsystem (e.g. You facade class calls **many objects** in subsystem).

But in Laravel's Facade it only has **one class** calls another **class** (not a subsystem). To me it looks more like a `Proxy` more than `Facade`. Can some one helps clarify this to me.

Answer (score 2):

The book, *Architect's Guide to PHP Design Patterns* notes,

> The purpose of the Facade is to present a simpler interface to an entire sub-system composed of many objects.

At my understanding, design patterns are not a "priori" obligation but rather a commitment to implement a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem.

Laravel 4 takes advantage of the Facade Design Pattern, which allows it to provide an expressive syntax through a static API but still keep it testable under the hood. The Facade hides the complexity / implementation of the code. 
Indeed, Laravel's [Facades](http://laravel.com/docs/facades) implement  a single object. We shouldn't neglect though that Laravel's App Facade (an IoC container) encapsulates the whole application .

A Proxy pattern intercepts a request and does extra work, for instance: filtering, ACL, transformation... The "consumer" Object is blissfully unaware of that extra work provided by the Proxy layer.